# Selected Item not being updated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, autopostback

I've got the following DropDownList control:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="SubjectFilter" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="SubjectFilter_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

`SubjectFilter` data:

```
BookStore b = new BookStore();
b.LoadFromXML(Server.MapPath("list.xml"));

SubjectFilter.DataSource = b.BooksList.Select(x => x.Subject).Distinct().ToArray();
SubjectFilter.DataBind();
SubjectFilter.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("הכל", "Default"));
```

Everything loads just fine. However in the `SubjectFilter_SelectedIndexChanged` method, `SubjectFilter.SelectedValue` is always `Default`, even though I'm selecting different options.

What is the problem?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that in your `Page_Load` that you only populate the dropdown when `IsPostBack` is false.

For example

```
 public void Page_Load(...)
 {
      if (!IsPostback())
          UpdateDisplay();
 }
```

Comment: This was my problem. I forgot it! Thank you very much (:

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the above code is from the `PageLoad` event. You may want to wrap that in a `if(!isPostBack)` block.

Answer (score 1):

When are you binding the drop down? You may any to wrap in an 
     If(page.ispostback ==false)
It looks like you may be binding on page load, before you check its value..

Answer (score 1):

ViewState is assigned between the Init and Load for an ASP.NET page. Your event handlers occur after load. If you are programmatically setting content in the controls that your user will be using, you want to handle that *before* ViewState is applied. In other words, move it to Page_Init. Afterwards, ViewState kicks in and you'll see what the user actually selected when your handler executes.